# 500 Internal Server Error. SecureTokenService

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, security-token-service

Environment: SharePoint 2013 (2 APP SERVERS & 2 WEB SERVERS)

Error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

EventViewer:

> An exception occcured when trying to issue security token. The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'

I tried the below url after IISRESET,it was working fine.

```
http://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc
```

But when I logged into the site and check the above URL throws 403 forbidden error.

Consecutively, the SP Site throws 500 Interval Server Error

Process:
IIS Reset -> securitytoken.svc(working fine) -> `http://spsite.com/` (working fine) -> `securitytoken.svc` (403 Forbidden) -> `http://spsite.com/` (500 Internal Server Error)

Notes:

- SecurityTokenApplicationPool is running under Farm admin account.
- SecurityTokenApplicationPool never stopped, even when it throws 403
  error.